# _SelectionChanged event doesn't recognize data with null fields

Tags: asp.net, devexpress, aspxgridview

I'm having some problems with the _SelectionChanged event on an ASPX grid view using devexpress v9.3.

The ASPX Gridview that is on the page doesn't recognize rows where some cells have no value. I can select rows where all of the cells have been populated and the keyFieldName is returned, however if some of the rows have no data it wont return anything.

I know each row has been assigned data for the KeyFieldName as I have outputted this to the grid.

Can anyone help me please x

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the issue. The grid view in my business logic was incorrect and I had applied the wrong variable to the keyfieldname.. Doh!